# Why gcc and clang both don't emit any warning?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

Suppose we have code like this:

```
int check(){
    int x = 5;

    ++x; /* line 1.*/

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    return check();
}
```

If `line 1` is commented out and the compiler is started with all warnings enabled, it emits:

```
warning: unused variable ‘x’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

However if we un-comment `line 1`, i.e. increase x, then no warning is emitted.

Why is that? Increasing the variable is not really using it.

This happen in both GCC and Clang for both [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: This sounds more of a definition what _using_ a variable means. Having a variable in a statement would, in my world, mean that I am using that variable.

Comment: Try with `-O3` ..

Comment: Being "used" has nothing to do with being "useful" :)

Comment: actually it would be annoying if the compiler really knew if a variable is not used. Sometimes you need a variable that appears not to be used and a common trick is to write `(void)x` to surpress the warning. If the compiler would recognize this as `x` not being used, then there would be no way to silence the warning

Comment: @tobi303: compiler can detect this idiom, and can suppress the warning in this case (and even, there could be a standardized [[unused]] attribute in the future).

Comment: And what if `x` wasn't of primitive type and its type would overload the meaning of `operator ++`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

`x++` is the same as `x = x+1;`, the assignment. When you are assigning to something, you possibly can not *skip* using it. The result is *not* discarded.

Also, from the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options), regarding `-Wunused-variable` option

> Warn whenever a local or static variable is **unused aside from its declaration.**

So, when you comment the `x++;`, it satisfies the condition to generate and emit the warning message. When you uncomment, the usage is visible to the compiler (the "usefulness" of this particular "usage" is questionable, but, it's an usage, nonetheless) and no warning.

Answer (score 4):

With the preincrement you are incrementing and **assigning** the value to the variable again. It is like:

```
x=x+1
```

As the gcc documentation says:

> -Wunused-variable:
>       Warn whenever a local or static variable is unused aside from its declaration.

If you comment that line you are not using the variable aside of the line in which you declare it

Comment: I'm with the OP, It's a self assignment and this value is a local (or automatic) variable, so it can't possibly be used out of this scope in this example.

So I find that odd that the compiler would stop emitting warnings.

Comment: @NadavL As the gcc documentation says:

Warn whenever a local or static variable is unused aside from its declaration.

And if he comment line 1, this condicition is met and the warning appears

Comment: Sounds legit, thanks! so the variable is still unused, but not in the sense defined in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

> increasing variable not really using it.

Sure this is *using it*. It's doing a read and a write access on the stored object. This operation doesn't have any effect *in your simple toy code*, and the optimizer might notice that and remove the variable altogether. But the logic behind the warning is much simpler: warn **iff** the variable is never used.

This has actually the benefit that you can silence that warning in cases where it makes sense:

```
void someCallback(void *data)
{
    (void)data; // <- this "uses" data

    // [...] handler code that doesn't need data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that? increasing variable not really using it.

Yes, it is really using it. At least from the language point of view. I would hope that an optimizer removes all trace of the variable.

Sure, that particular use has no effect on the rest of the program, so the variable is indeed redundant. I would agree that warning in this case would be helpful. But that is not the purpose of the warning about being unused, that you mention.

However, consider that analyzing whether a particular variable has any effect on the execution of the program in general is quite difficult. There has to be a point where the compiler stops checking whether a variable is actually useful. It appears that the stages that generate warnings of the compilers that you tested only check whether the variable is used at least once. That once was the increment operation.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misconception about the word 'using' and what the compiler means with that. When you have a `++i` you are not only accessing the variable, you are even modifying it, and AFAIK this counts as 'use'.

There are limitations to what the compiler can identify as 'how' variables are being used, and if the statements make any sense. In fact both clang and gcc will try to remove unnecessary statements, depending on the `-O`-flag (sometimes too aggressively). But these optimizations happen without warnings.

Detecting a variable that is never ever accessed or used though (there is no further statement mentioning that variable) is rather easy.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, it could generate a warning about this. I think it doesn't generate a warning, because developers of the compilers just didn't bothered handling this case (yet). Maybe it is because it is too complicated to do. But maybe they will do this in the future (hint: you can suggest them this warning).

Compilers getting more and more warnings. For example, there is `-Wunused-but-set-variable` in GCC (which is a "new" warning, introduced in GCC 4.6 in 2011), which warns about this:

```
void fn() {
    int a;
    a = 2;
}
```

So it is completely fine to expect that this emits a warning too (there is nothing different here, neither codes do anything useful):

```
void fn() {
    int a = 1;
    a++;
}
```

Maybe they could add a new warning, like `-Wmeaningless-variable`

Comment: It's tricky.  Sometimes an induction variable can be optimized away completely, but you'd only want the warning when the variable has no interaction with anything else.  I guess an interesting warning would be when the last operation on a dead variable was a write / assignment.  So `(void)a` at the end of a function would still silence a warning for `a++`.

Answer (score 0):

As per C standard **ISO/IEC 9899:201x**, expressions evaluation are always executed to allow for expression's side effects to be produced unless the compiler can't be sufficiently sure that removing it the program execution is not altered.

> **5.1.2.3 Program execution**
>
> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).

When removing the line

```
++x;
```

The compiler can deduce that the local variable `x` is defined and initialized, but not used.

When you add it, the expression itself can be considered a `void` expression, that **must be evaluated for side effects**, as stated in:

> **6.8.3 Expression and null statements**
>
> The expression in an expression statement is evaluated as a void expression for its side effects.

On the other hand to remove compiler warnings relative to unused variable is very common to cast the expression to void. I.e. for an unused parameter in a function you can write:

```
int MyFunc(int unused)
{
   (void)unused;
   ...
   return a;
}
```

In this case we have a void expression that reference the symbol `unused`.

Comment: An *optimizing* compiler can still optimizes away a variable entirely.  Note the word "needed" in: *An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no **needed** side effects are produced*".  It would be kinda nice if there was a warning for this, but `-Wunused-variable` is not it.  This answer doesn't really justify that, though, because `++x` is not a *needed* side-effect, because `x` is dead after that (nothing reads it).

Comment: @PeterCordes The pre/post increment/decrement operators are a kind of **institutional side effect operators** because they produce  a side effect creating 2 values before and after application. Even if `x++;` can be write as `x=x+1;` **it is not at all an equivalent**. For the specification grammar The first is a **null statement**, only producing side effects (an increment), and the second is an **assignement expression**. In the case of the null statement you shall apply what is described in **6.8.3 Expressions and null statement**. Continue...

Comment: @PeterCordes Removing the expression `x++;` the declaration (see **6.7 Declarations**), with initialization, `int x=5;` standing alone **is an unused variable**. Then the compiler tells you that you can remove the warning using the switch `-Wunused-variable`. An abstract machine could eventually avoid the evaluation of **part of it** if **it is able to decide that the code is ininfluent**, or let it alone.